# R Shiny: shinydashboardPlus appButton inputId

Tags: shinydashboard

How do I capture the click event of the `appButton` in `shinydashboardPlus` as it doesn't have an `inputId`?

https://rdrr.io/cran/shinydashboardPlus/man/appButton.html